# How to create a self-closing HTML tag with JS

Tags: javascript, html

need help.
How can i create a single tag

i have a HTML doc with JS script.

**HTML**

```
<div id="root"></div>
```

**JS**

```
const div = document.querySelector('#root');
```

i try this

```
const mySingleElem = document.createElement('single');
mySingleElem.setAttribute('name', 'test');
div.appendChild(mySingleElem);
```

despite the fact that there is no content, a pair tag is created

**HTML**

```
<div id="root">
    <single name="test"></single>
</div>
```

How can i create a single tag ?

```
<single name="test"/>
```

*Еhank you for your attention*

Comment: First of all `single` isn't a [valid HTML tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element). Furthermore why do you need an self-closing tag? It doesn't add anything a normal closing tag can't do.

Comment: You mean a self-closing tag?

Comment: Self-closing tags don't exist in html. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Void_element

Comment: yes, a self-closing tag, thanks.

Comment: Нes, I understand that this is not a standard tag, the task is related to XML and it is necessary that such a tag be displayed in DOM

Comment: Looks like the answer is a big NO. See: [GitHub #624 - Custom 'void' or self-closing elements (HTML parser changes)](https://github.com/WICG/webcomponents/issues/624#issuecomment-370310607)

Comment: If it is XML, why are you not creating XML?

Answer (score 0):

When browsers serialise a DOM to HTML they normalise it.

Elements with forbidden end tags will be expressed as just a start tag.

Other elements, including invalid ones (like `single`) will have start and end tags.

There is no way around this beyond post-processing or writing a custom serialiser.